# a csv bulk data loading into postgres is not working using COPY or \copy on osx Mavericks

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

i am just trying to do a bulk data loading using this way and i am finding problems. I have just created an user in my osx system, tom/mypass, then i have just created the user and the database, then the tables:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:~ aironman$ psql template1
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# CREATE USER tom WITH PASSWORD 'mypass';
CREATE ROLE
template1=# CREATE DATABASE "TrialDB";
CREATE DATABASE
template1=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "TrialDB" to tom;
GRANT

TrialDB=> CREATE TABLE core2door_element
TrialDB-> (
TrialDB(>   id serial NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   key character varying(255) NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   label character varying(255) NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   longitude double precision NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   latitude double precision NOT NULL,
TrialDB(>   parent_id integer,
TrialDB(>   CONSTRAINT core2door_element_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
TrialDB(>   CONSTRAINT core2door_element_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
TrialDB(>       REFERENCES core2door_element (id) MATCH SIMPLE
TrialDB(>       ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
TrialDB(> )
TrialDB-> WITH (
TrialDB(>   OIDS=FALSE
TrialDB(> );
CREATE TABLE
TrialDB=> ALTER TABLE core2door_element OWNER TO tom;
ALTER TABLE
```

Now, if i try to launch COPY command:

```
TrialDB=> COPY core2door(id,key,type,label,longitude,latitude,parent_id) FROM '/Users/aironman/Documents/tektroniks/fake_data_entity.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

COPY is not working, trying with \copy:

```
TrialDB=> \copy core2door(id,key,type,label,longitude,latitude,parent_id) FROM '/Users/aironman/Documents/tektroniks/fake_data_entity.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
/Users/aironman/Documents/tektroniks/fake_data_entity.csv: Permission denied
```

permission denied too!

As you can see, the csv file have every permission:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:tektroniks aironman$ ls -l fake_data_entity.csv 
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 aironman staff 351 sep 15 09:53 fake_data_entity.csv
```

what do i am doing wrong?

my apologies if this is a already answered question, but searching within this site, every question is already solved theorically using my way, but unfortunately for me, it is not working.

Comment: You don't only need read access to the file but also *at least* `x` access to to directories in the path that leads to it. Home directories typically have no `x` bit set (for good reasons) easyest way is to copy or move the file to `/tmp/` and read it from there.

Comment: Thank you sir, i move the file to my /tmp dir and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Joop is correct. Sorry for the delay

You don't only need read access to the file but also at least x access to to directories in the path that leads to it. Home directories typically have no x bit set (for good reasons) easyest way is to copy or move the file to /tmp/ and read it from there.